# Long Polling: Stuck in while loop

Tags: ajax, post-meta

I'm trying to write a long polling function, that only returns data to the client as soon as some custom post_meta is updated. This custom post_meta is a unix time stamp, which is then compared to the unix timestamp sent to the function by the client via AJAX. If the post_meta value is higher than the client value, the post_meta value is sent back to the client. But for some reason the function keeps stuck in the while loop, that compares the two timestamps. The unix timestamps seem to be properly formatted and can be compared without problems, i tried that outside the while loop. But while inside the while loop and the post_meta gets updated in the meantime, the while loop won't stop. It seems the condition for the while loop does never seem to change, regardless of the updated (and of course higher) value in the database. What am i missing?

```
function my_sync_function () { 

$post_id = intval(wp_strip_all_tags($_GET['post_id'])); // make post ID integer

$lastRequest = wp_strip_all_tags($_GET['timestamp']); // unix timestamp

$lastModified = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'last_modified', true ); // unix timestamp

// do nothing until the lastModified timestamp is greater than the lastRequest timestamp
while ($lastModified <= $lastRequest) {
    usleep(2000000);           
    clearstatcache();    
    $lastModified = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'last_modified', true ); // check for updated timestamp       
}

$result['type'] = 'success';
$result['timestamp'] = $lastModified;
$result = json_encode($result);
echo $result;

die();
}
    add_action('wp_ajax_my_sync_function', 'my_sync_function');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not a multi tasking language, you should not try to use it as such. In other words, long polling is not something you should try to even attempt unless you use a language construct designed to support it.

Specifically to your question, you probably fail because wordpress has the habit of caching in memory as mach info that is retrieved from the DB as it can  (this is core feature, no plugins involved). To the best of my memory once post metadata is retrieved it is cached and therefor `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'last_modified', true )` always returns the same value. You need to invalidate the cache to be able to do what you are trying to, or send a query to the DB bypassing the WP API.

In addition your code has very bad influence on the performance of the server as you get one apache process busy without doing anything useful, which if you have the apache to run 10 processes means that you can serve 10% less requests at the time your code is working.

Another factor is the php execution time limit which is usually set to 30 seconds, therefor your long polling process will just die after 30 seconds without giving you any notification about it.

Comment: Right on point, wordpress cache was the problem here. Thanks a lot! Considering your performance concerns, i think i'll have a closer look at websocket. Thanks again!